# Get Java Object Using A Reference

Tags: java, object, reflection, reference, rmi

I have this question on my mind and I severely need to find an answer for it.

**My problem:** How to get a reference of the object (something like memory address) then get the object using the reference (note: I know where the object located (in an array)). I hear there are ways to do what I want to do using the *Unsafe* class, or even *JNA* (I lack knowledge of both of them, but happy to learn!)

**What I'm doing:**

I have made an application **(app1)** which is inserted into another application**(app2)** through Instrumentation and this application **(app1)** sends data fetched from **(app2)** through the Reflection API to another application of mine **(app3)** through RMI. The objects in the array change constantly in terms of values, so what I'm doing is fetching the objects and reading their data but my problem comes when I try to get updated data using the previously obtained object which is normally done by `getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(PreviouslyObtainedObject);` but I can't keep the previously obtained object on the current application (app1) due to it being Unserializable so I need to get a reference of this object so I can get it later on.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried doing it using HashCode but HashCode just keeps changing/dissppears whenever the object's values change and the hashCode might be the same with other objects so this creates another problem.

I've tried doing it using XStream,GSON,etc.. but using the xml/json it creates a new object and doesn't relate to the previously obtained object. so when I try to get updated info about the object using the JSON/XML created object it returns the old info as it does not equal the previously obtained object. So like `getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(PreviouslyObtainedObject)` returns updated information about the object but `getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(JSON/XMLVersionOfPreviouslyObtainedObject)` does not return new data.

I can't do Object -> byte Array due to the objects being unserializable.

There's no code in the question because I felt that the code won't serve a purpose to the question. to get more information about what I'm doing you could view a previous question of mine: [Getting an Object by reference in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067030/getting-an-object-by-reference-in-java)
Note: there's a difference between this question and my previous one as the previous one discussed ways of wrapping or turning the objects into JSON or XML format and this one is just for getting a reference.

**Summary of what I'm trying to do (for more clarity):**

I have **2** applications:
first app (**app1**): Application which is instrumented into another application (to gather data and send)

second app (**app2**): Application which receives the data from the instrumented data and does logic..

app1 gets the data from the application its instrumented into via the Reflection API so like (getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(object/null);)
app1 send the Object reference (memory address/hashCode/this is what I want) and the current values of the object  to **app2**. **app2** sends back the reference whenever it wants and gets the object updated data.

so like in code terms:

The first time I want to get an object, I access an object array using reflection then loop through it to find my perfect object like this:

```
Object[] obArray = (Object[]) getClassLoader().loadClass("className").getDeclaredField("fieldName").get(null);
for(Object ob : obArray) {
    if(ob is what I want) return ob;
}
```

then If I wanted to get updated information of ob (object that I fetched above). I do `getClassLoader().loadClass(className).getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(ob);`

Now due to the amount of objects I process I can't store the objects I fetched on the same application so I must get a reference to them (something like a memory address or hashCode) to send to **app2** so that **app2** can send it back to **app1** at a later date to get the object back and get updated information about it.

Comment: The way to pass objects between multiple programs in java is to either transfer the objects or the changes. You cannot just access an object from another application.

Comment: @dan1st I'm not trying to access an object from another application, what I want to do is get a reference of the object (on the same application) then send the reference to the other app through RMI or Sockets or w/e then when I want to get updated information of the object I send the reference to the application and get information about the object then send the information. I'll edit my question and make it more clearer

Comment: You can also not send references over RMI. You can only transfer serializable objects and update the origin object afterwards. Those are different objects in different processes.

Comment: @dan1st What I meant by references.. is for an example.. object memory address or hashCode or whatever integer/long is needed to get the object back.. please read the summary of my question (that I added just now) will make what I want to do more clearer

Comment: The `hashCode` just gives you a hash of the data - ideally. And you cannot share references to objects.

Comment: @dan1st I understand but is there anything I could use to get the object back at a later being that I know where the object is (in an array) I heard that there is something I can do using UnSafe or JNA. I've been scrambling around for more than a week because of this problem and can't proceed with my app :(

Comment: You can only create a `Map<>` where the key is a unique id that is shared and thr value is the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225494/discussion-between-adam-mkw-and-dan1st).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using RMI, you are already using a framework maintaining references across JVMs. But it does not support retrieving the original local object reference after passing a reference to another JVM and back, as it only allows communicating with the referenced object through the remote interface.

But since your actual goal is to allow reading the fields of a referenced object, you can export this operation through the remote interface.

Here’s a sketch for such an access. Note that it bears several things you wouldn’t do in the producing code (like setting `sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval` to an insanely small value), for demonstration purposes.

```java
public class RmiApp implements RmiAppB {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval", "1000");
        if(args.length == 0) runAppB(); else runAppA();
    }

    private static void runAppA() throws Exception {
        String me = String.format("App A (pid%6d) ", ProcessHandle.current().pid());
        System.out.println(me + "started");
        Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(12348);
        RmiAppB appB = (RmiAppB)r.lookup("foo");
        InnocuousObject obj = new InnocuousObject("a local string", 42, 1.234f);
        System.out.println(me + "sending reference");
        appB.passTheReference((WrappingReference)
            UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new WrappingReferenceImpl(obj), 0));

        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        System.out.println(me + "changing fields");
        obj.field1 = "another string";
        obj.field2 = 0;
        obj.field3 = 0.1f;
        obj = null; // we don't need to keep a strong reference

        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(5));

        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void runAppB() throws Exception {
        System.out.printf("App B (pid%6d) started%n", ProcessHandle.current().pid());
        Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(12348);
        r.bind("foo", UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new RmiApp(), 0));
        //UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new RmiApp(), 12345);
        new ProcessBuilder(
            Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin", "java").toString(),
            "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
            RmiApp.class.getName(), "runA")
            .inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void passTheReference(WrappingReference o) throws RemoteException {
        String me = String.format("App B (pid%6d) ", ProcessHandle.current().pid());
        System.out.println(me + "received object");
        System.out.println(me + "querying field1 " + o.getField("field1"));
        System.out.println(me + "querying field2 " + o.getField("field2"));
        System.out.println(me + "querying field3 " + o.getField("field3"));
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(3));
            try {
                System.out.println(me + "querying field1 " + o.getField("field1"));
                System.out.println(me + "querying field2 " + o.getField("field2"));
                System.out.println(me + "querying field3 " + o.getField("field3"));
            } catch(RemoteException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}

interface RmiAppB extends Remote {
    void passTheReference(WrappingReference o) throws RemoteException;
}

interface WrappingReference extends Remote {
    Object getField(String nra) throws RemoteException;
}

class WrappingReferenceImpl implements WrappingReference {
    InnocuousObject referent;

    WrappingReferenceImpl(InnocuousObject referent) {
        this.referent = referent;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getField(String nra) throws RemoteException {
        try {
            return referent.getClass().getDeclaredField(nra).get(referent);
        } catch(NoSuchFieldException|IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RemoteException(null, ex);
        }
    }
}

class InnocuousObject {
    String field1;
    int field2;
    float field3;

    public InnocuousObject(String field1, int field2, float field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("InnocuousObject.finalize()");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return field1;
    }
}
```

In one run, it printed

```
App B (pid  8924) started
App A (pid  9132) started
App A (pid  9132) sending reference
App B (pid  8924) received object
App B (pid  8924) querying field1 a local string
App B (pid  8924) querying field2 42
App B (pid  8924) querying field3 1.234
App A (pid  9132) changing fields
App B (pid  8924) querying field1 another string
App B (pid  8924) querying field2 0
App B (pid  8924) querying field3 0.1
InnocuousObject.finalize()
```

showing how the remote reference kept the object alive as long as the other JVM held a remote reference, but allowed its garbage collection when no remote reference existed.

Further note the important point that the target `InnocuousObject` has no awareness about the remote access via the encapsulating `WrappingReferenceImpl` that performed the reflective access. This seems to support your scenario of having app2 instrumented by app1 whereas only app1 is aware of the remote access.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) Much appreciated. But I do need to get back to the reference I got via Reflection <- that's the problem, I have to return to the same object.. I cannot create an XML object of it or anything similar .. so What I have done for the time being is create a ReferenceMap<Integer,Object> where the integer is the key (strong) and the object is the needed object.. (weak). So now what I can do is get info about the object by get the objects back using their keys.. and if they are nullified.. they are booted off the map automatically

Comment: This previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067030/getting-an-object-by-reference-in-java/65098663#65098663 of mine explains what I'm doing bit by bit better than I explained it in this question. 

If you have a better way of doing rather than creating a weak map, please do tell and once again I appreciate EVERY second you've put into creating your answer

Comment: what about if there were many objects.. and sub-object or even sub-sub-objects of the object

Comment: won't this cost a lot? in terms of memory

Comment: It takes what it needs. There is no way around using resources for what you are doing. For “sub-objects”, you have to decide whether you want to export them or serialize them. Each strategy has its kind of costs. You could create an object supporting to traverse a path, expressed as string array, to transfer only the last object instead of all intermediate, but this requires predictable result types, to know the existing fields before-hand. I don’t know your object graph, so I can’t calculate the actual costs for you.

Comment: Its attached to a game so all kinds of objects must be transferred. from gameObjects to tiles etc.. also there are arrays which I loop through (has like 2000 elements+) so exporting will cost a lot won't it? Is there a way to put the objects off heap by DirectByteBuffer? then transferring a byte array?

Comment: Your description so far (including `getDeclaredField(fieldName)` etc) sounded like a monitoring or debugging interface, not something like a production environment (such terms apply to games as well). Don’t do this at all. Develop a real communication protocol allowing to transfer differences to the previous state and maintain the game state on both sides. Then, there is no need to worry about garbage collection. Either, the client is connected or not. As long as there is a connection, you’ll have to maintain the entire game state anyway.

Comment: The game isn't mine, app1 is connected to the game's JVM (Java Attach API) and grabs fields using reflection. that's why im looking for unorthodox methods..

Comment: Then, you trying to build a reliable and performant application atop something that is inherently unreliable and inefficient. But still, the Attach API allows you to load code into that JVM and establish a useful communication protocol between that code and your client.

Comment: I understand that it's something unreliable, but I need to keep the JVM of the game as light as possible and to keep the garbage collection frequency stable and unchanged (or a bit changed). I'm thinking about ByteBuffers. what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226817/discussion-between-adam-mkw-and-holger).